# Cordova is not wrapping Angular proxy configuration

Tags: angular, cordova, web-applications, hybrid-mobile-app

I am currently working on wrapping an angular UI using Apache Cordova. The angular UI accesses an API by following a proxy to  `http://localhost:8080` which is hosting a server application. The proxy configuration, `proxy.conf.json` is as follow:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
    },
}
```

The Angular UI works as long as the server application is up. But after wrapping up the UI, the Cordova app does not work, it only shows a blank screen and the error shows `Failed to load resource: http://localhost:8000/api/xx/xx the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.

I think this might be because of Cordova not wrapping the `proxy.conf.json`. I have tried whitelisting it using `cordova-plugin-whitelist` but still does not work.

Are there any other way to configure the proxy for the Cordova app to access the API?